# Build Criteria API Query Builder in compile time manner (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria

i chanced upon this Criteria example

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/Criteria

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = qb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
query.where(qb.equal(employee.get("firstName"), "Bob"));
List<Employee> result = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
...
```

My question is, is there anyway i can specify the field name (firstName) in a compile time manner?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the fieldname as a variable?

```
String filterField = "firstName";
query.where(qb.equal(employee.get(filterField), "Bob"));
```

Using it in a dynamic way should be the main point of that api.